# AngularJS Search using Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to have a search box search values in a table. My code currently works fine.

```
<tr ng-repeat="b in bugs | filter:searchText">
```

However, I wish to go further and give users the ability to search specific columns if they have a colon in their search text (e.g. "id: 3").

I have managed to split the search text, separating the column name from the field text.

I read in AngularJS you can do searchText.id to filter specific columns. However, my table has quite a few columns and I only have a string of the column name.

My question is, what is the best way to dynamically set the column being filtered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the column you're searching by accessing it with array syntax.

```
searchText.id; 
var columnName = "id";
searchText[columnName]; // same thing
```